# Android how to set run time Id

Tags: java, android, performance, android-activity, android-studio

I want to set run time id and get id.
my code is...

```
TextView image=new TextView(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageParams = new       LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100,100);
            image.setLayoutParams(imageParams);
                image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey);
            image.setId(1);
   image.setOnclickListner(this);
```

but When I set image.setId(1) then give the error in android studio.
then how to find image id in under the view..

Comment: what is error you are getting

Comment: error is      Expected resource of type id

Comment: #Destro ur code is absolutly fine ... please check somethings else causing this error

Comment: this error is show only Android studio.. same code is run in eclipse

Comment: try changing id to some bigger number

Comment: View.generateViewId()  use this in image.setid(View.generateViewId());

Comment: thanks  but how to find this id..under the View.. means when the click this image then how to find image id

Comment: just after setid you can  also call getid it will return assigned id

Comment: but  image.setid(View.generateViewId()); is set in when minimum API level is 17 .. but in my project is working API level is 13..

Comment: @Destro What's the need to set resource id dynamically?

Comment: @Bhavik mehta  I am set many imageView ya textView in run time and set clicklistener in all imageView ya TextView when click image ya text then find some  response .

Comment: @Destro why worrying about ids then? you can simply do this by i.e(image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener) ) as simple as that, make a counter and attach that counter with the image name so no conflict may occur

Comment: @Bhavik Mehta  in my layout at a time 32 image is adding in run time so this code is not possible..your code is valid when adding only one image

Comment: @Destro, Can you explain the work flow if possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71644/discussion-between-destro-and-bhavik-mehta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in below API level 17 there is not possible to generate run time ID.. if we generate id then we set Tag like as image.setTag(1) .. for example..

```
TextView image=new TextView(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageParams = new       LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100,100);
        image.setLayoutParams(imageParams);
            image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey);
        image.setTag(1);
     image.setOnclickListner(this);
}
```

and get Tag like this

```
  @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.e("hello",""+v.getTag());

}
```